# How can I transfer files from Windows XP PC to Windows 8.1 PC?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8.1, file-transfer, data-transfer

I need help to transfer my files from my old computer that has Windows XP to my new PC that has WIndows 8.1. I know it will be easier to just buy an external hard drive but I'm not able to do that right now.

Comment: Do you have a USB or anything? If the size isn't big enough and would take too many transfers, consider a web-based service like Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Why not just use a network cable?

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of methods you could use. One method you could use would be to configure one of the systems as a [Secure Shell (SSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_shell) server and use a SSH client on the other. You could could then transfer files from one to the other using the [Secure File Transfer Protocol (SFTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). You could, for instance, install [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/) on the Windows 8.1 PC and then install the free SFTP program [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) on the Windows XP system. You could then establish an SFTP connection from the XP system to the 8.1 system and transfer files over the network. Note: if there are any firewalls between the two, you would need to configure an appropriate firewall rule.

If you are unfamiliar with SSH and SFTP, the easiest course might be, instead, to use [TeamViewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer), which is software that allows you to remotely control one system from another or transfer files between the systems. It is free for personal use. You would install it on both systems. It is very easy to set up and use.

Or you could use free cloud-based solutions, such as [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive), which would allow you to synchronize files and folders between the two systems while also even maintaining a copy of the files on a server within the cloud service provider's network, if you wished.